# switching from Hibernate to JPA Interface that implements Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm not exactly sure how to phrase my question, but I have been working through a hibernate tutorial and everything has been smooth sailing until we switched from using the hibernate.cfg.xml to a resources/META-INF/persistance.xml. It seems that the program cannot create an EntityManagerFactory object, and is throwing an XsdException. After trying to research what that exception is, im not exactly sure what it means, or how to fix it. at this point just starting a session and closing the transaction would be a big step. what am i doing wrong? am i not putting the persistance.xml file in the right spot? any directional advice would be greatly appreciated...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/util/xml/XsdException
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:80)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at ApplicationJPA.main(ApplicationJPA.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XsdException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 11 more
```

src/main/java/applicationJPA.java (driver)

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class ApplicationJPA {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("infinite-finances");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx =  em.getTransaction();

    tx.begin();

    em.close();
    emf.close();

}
}
```

src/main/recourses/META-INF/persistance.xml

```
 <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="infinite-finances" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="passwprd"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infinite_skills"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <!-- Create/update tables automatically using mapping metadata -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.infiniteSkills</groupId>
<artifactId>ifinance-hibernateTut</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but could be the hibernate-entitymanager dependency, switch to this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: quite obvious :) - "hibernate-annotations" should also be set to the correct version